# ab Failed Requests

Tags: load-testing, ab

I've built a simple apache + django + mod_wsgi webapp that I am testing on my local machine.

I've started load testing it using ab - and I am seeing a few failed requests.

```
ab -n 500 -c 100 "http://localhost/"

output:
....
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        27
```

In my apache config I have turned keepalive OFF and all the config for MaxClients & MaxKeepAliveRequests is set to 150. As I am starting 100 connections I dont think that I am hitting that limit. Top says that I'm not running out of memory either

How can I reduce the number of failed requests?

Also is there any log/record of these failed requests? - because there is nothing in the apache log.

Comment: You need a tool that will give you some more information about the failures. For example, did the connections fail? Did it accept the request and return a response with a status code indicating an error? Ideally, you'd like to capture the full HTTP responses (if present).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) or [weighttp](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/weighttp/wiki) instead of ab.

Both of them provide more details than ab about failed requests.